# Wwise with Unity Rigidbody 2d or Collider 2d

Tags: unity, rigidbody, wwise

I'm half way in making a 2D game in Unity and found that Wwise needed the game objects to have a normal 3D RigidBody, since that's quite some work to replace everything, is there any way around?

Comment: what is Wwise? you need to at least provide some link(s) that defines Wwise

Comment: Thanks for helping, Wwise is an audio middleware https://www.audiokinetic.com/en/

Comment: @HamzaHasan you can also look at the tag wiki :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could script the replacement. If you have a common script for all the objects that need to use Wwise:

```
if(this.GetComponent<RigidBody2D>() != null)
{
    this.Destroy(this.GetComponent<RigidBody2D>());
    RigidBody newBody = this.AddComponent<RigidBody>();
    //Make whatever config changes you need to newBody
}
```

However, this is kind of a clunky way to do it, since it only replaces the items at runtime, and will have to replace every time.

An editor script is a better way to approach. This supposedly will add a menu item to run this script in the editor. I say supposedly because it's completely untested. The premise is the same though, find objects that have your component of interest, then remove that component and add a new component of the type you want.

```
class Replace2DComponents extends Editor
 {
     @MenuItem ("CustomCommands/Replace2D")
     static function Replace2D() 
     {
         List<GameObject> rigid2ds = new List<GameObject>();
         rigid2ds.AddRange(FindObjectsOfType(typeof(RigidBody2D) as GameObject);
         for(GameObject obj in rigid2ds)
         {
             DestroyImmediate(obj.GetComponent<RigidBody2D>());
             RigidBody newBody = obj.AddComponent<RigidBody>();
             //other config changes for newBody
         }
     }
 }
```

Finally, you shouldn't be in this situation in the first place. You should be using prefabs to create your game objects, and should thus only need to make your changes in a few places to get the desired effect.